# angular-material2 responsive show/hide

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is it possible to control visibility of element with angular-material2 using

```
hide-xx  show-xx hide-gt-xx show-gt-xx
```

i know this is working with angularJS-material.
Code below does not work:

```
<md-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>Application Title</span>  
  <span class="example-fill-remaining-space"></span>
  <button md-button hide-xs show-gt-xs>Auto hide button</button>  
</md-toolbar>
```

I use https://github.com/angular/material2 version 2.0.0

If No, if there is another way to do that without using *ngif and screen resize listeners, or other css frameworks like Bootstrap ?
Also does https://github.com/angular/flex-layout has this possibility by the way?

Comment: What do you mean *is another way to do that without using \*ngif and screen resize listeners, or other css frameworks like Bootstrap*?

Comment: I don't want to use Bootstrap along with Material because i heard of some "conflicts/overrides" in css. And about ngif - i want to use logic in html template without using controller side (typescript files)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I would recommend **@angular/flex-layout**, as you already mentioned!

It's an *additional* package - installation
needed, it's not a part of angular!

Possible options:

- fxHide
- fxHide.xs
- fxHide.gt-xs
- fxHide.sm
- fxHide.gt-sm
- fxHide.md
- fxHide.gt-md
- fxHide.lg
- fxHide.gt-lg
- fxHide.xl

Usage:

```html
<div fxFlex="60" fxHide.xs></div>
```

live-demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/yrhaGtFpHOlYYOTqzDDO?p=preview

documentation here:

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxShow-API

https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxHide-API

Comment: Where is the documentation for this? I hate having to google for every class or feature they already have out of the box

Comment: i guess there is currently only the wiki: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki

Comment: Thank you. Your answer should break records soon. It's the only Googled answer thus far

Comment: Documentation here: https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxShow-API https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/fxHide-API

Comment: It should be noted that `@angular/flex-layout` does not come packaged with angular cli you will have to install it in your app `npm install @angular/flex-layout@latest --save` and import it in your `app.module` `import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout'`